# Can't access template created through innerHTML directive, Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to access to the elements of the DOM of a component dinamically created through innerHTML directive in Angular.
This is my main component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-block [template]="template"></app-block>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

protected template = `
      <main role="main" class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading text-center">Cover your page.</h1>
        <p #paragraph class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. 
        Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
        <p #paragraph class="lead">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </main>
  `;
}
```

and this is my component created dinamically:

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  Input,
  ViewChildren,
 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-block',
  template: `    
    <div [innerHTML]="template"></div>
  `
})
export class BlockComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() template: String;
  @ViewChildren('paragraph') ps;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.ps.length);
  }
}
```

I just tried to get the length of my object but it seems to be empty. Like it can't see the template auto-generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular by default won't allow you to inject dynamic HTML into the template, since it's a security concern (Cross Site Scripting, read [here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#security-risk)).

However you can bypass the sanitizing as mentioned in the docs linked above, using a pipe would be the most straight forward solution:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHTML'})
export class SanitizeHtml implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(html): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

And you would edit your template to use that pipe: